# Advanced Custom Fields Multisite Upload/Imagery Issue

Tags: multisite, uploads, advanced-custom-fields

OK, so I'm using:

- **WordPress 4.4.1** *(the latest version at this time)*
- **Advanced Custom Fields PRO v5.3.3.2** *(the latest version at this time)*

I'm having a very strange issue that I cannot seem to fix. I have a multisite setup with five or so websites. They all share the same theme, and have different domain names per site.

Throughout the site, I use ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) to pull in imagery, for example at the top of each page there's a banner.

The primary site works fine, you can upload images, and when you add an image to a page using ACF, they pull through correctly. These images sit on: `/wp-content/uploads/year/month`.

Now the issue I'm experiencing is on my other sites, not the primary one, images are stored in `/wp-content/uploads/sites/siteID/year/month`. Uploading imagery works fine, but when I upload/select an image to use on ACF, they do not show on the front end. When I inspect element on these images, I can see that the path in incorrect. It's not looking in the `/sites/` directory.

I read that I needed to set the `upload path` in the network admin settings for each site. I can fix it so that ACF looks in the right place for the images, but then I'm unable to upload or view imagery in the media library.

Comment: Just to add, I know I could fix this by hacking around in my templates to run find and replaces on the URLs pulled in, but I'd rather an actual solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wp\_get\_attachment\_image\_src multisite issue](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215691/wp-get-attachment-image-src-multisite-issue)

Answer (score 0):

I've ruled out this being an issue with Advanced Custom Fields, so I've made a new question. For more information, please look at:
[wp_get_attachment_image_src multisite issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/215691/wp-get-attachment-image-src-multisite-issue)